# CSS media queries [how to transform to hyperlinks via media queries]

Tags: css, hyperlink

does anyone know how to change HTML text to hyperlinks everytime the web is resize to smartphone portrait?

For example:

Item List:
-Cup
-Keys
-Bags

when the screen is being resized the Item list should be transformed to hyperlinks as the cup, keys and bags will be hidden.

Comment: You should start off with the basics and read about CSS, HTML and what the difference is. You also should get in touch with the basic concepts of media queries and how they work. There are just too many things to explain here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a extra Div which is filled with the hyperlinks. And give it display: none.

And then give it display block with a media query. And display non on the current div.

But changing text using media queries is not possible. You can only change up CSS with the media queries.